# Foreach statement cannot operate on type ' ' because it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

I have the following in my Api Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public Model.ViewModel.ContactSaveRequest DeleteMethod(Model.ViewModel.ContactSaveRequest methodsToDelete)
{
    var contactMethodRepos = new Model.ContactMethodRepository();

    foreach (var contactMethod in methodsToDelete)
    {
        contactMethodRepos.Delete(contactMethod);
        return contactMethod;
    }
}
```

This is my class defining a contact method

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public int ID { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("contactID")]
public int ContactID { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("typeOfContactMethodID")]
public int TypeOfContactMethodID { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("text")]
public string Text { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("methodsToDelete")]
public IEnumerable<ContactMethod> methodsToDelete { get; set; }
```

`ContactSaverequest` class:

```
public class ContactSaveRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("contact")]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactMethods")]
    public IEnumerable<ContactMethod> ContactMethods { get; set; }        
}
```

I have an array which pushes methods into it to be deleted (`methodsToDelete`). I am trying to use the `Delete` method on the array but keep getting the issue that `contactSaveRequest` doesn't contain a definition for `GetEnumerator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use:

```
foreach (var contactMethod in methodsToDelete.ContactMethods)
```

You can't iterate over a `ContactSaveRequest`, but you *can* iterate over the `IEnumerable<ContactMethod>` that is returned by the `ContactMethods` property.

Comment: @moleman: "that doesn't seem to work" doesn't give us any useful information. What goes wrong when you try that?

Comment: Sorry, it says that 'the name contact does not exist in the current context'.

Comment: @moleman: Oh, right - fixed now. I would have hoped you could have worked out that typo though, if you'd understood the answer. (It's always more important to understand the answer than to just plug in the code and hope.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement IEnumerable interface like this

public class ContactSaveRequest : IEnumerable 
{

}